# EntityFramework cannot catch DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having an issue with catching the DbUpdateException when deleting an object that is related to other tables from MySQL database and DbContext.SaveChanges() throws that exact exception.

The following code does not catch the exception:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<JobTitle>> DeleteJobtitle(int id) {
        var jobtitle = await _context.Jobtitle.FindAsync(id);

        if (jobtitle == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Jobtitle.Remove(jobtitle);

        try {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("exception: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return jobtitle;
    }
```

And this is the console output when exception occurs:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
  Failed executing DbCommand (1,601ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  DELETE FROM `jobtitle`
  WHERE `idJobTitle` = @p0;
  SELECT ROW_COUNT();
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
  An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbAPI.DbContexts.DbContext'.
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

Why doesn't my try catch block catch the exception?

Comment: Have you ensured that the exception thrown is of type DbUpdateException ?

Comment: I don't think they print to console, much more likely they use default logging and pipe the error with the message into the logging, which you did configure to write to console. Regards Alexander

Comment: And what's the solution? I have the same problem, see an error in the output, but can't catch it.